# Java String date comparator

Tags: java, android, comparator

I have a list of Channels, named channelsList.

```
List<Channel> channelsList;
```

Channel Class

```
public class Channel{
    public Conversation conversation;
}
```

Conversation Class

```
public class Conversation{
    public String sentAt;
}
```

I need to Sort the channel list in descending order of myDate. How can I use comparator for this? I tried this so far. But this is not working as my collection Channel can have null values for conversation and Conversation can have null values for sentAt. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Collections.sort(channelsList, new Comparator<Channel>() {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN);

        @Override
        public int compare(Channel o1, Channel o2) {
            try {
                if (o1.getConversation() != null && Util.isUTCFormat(o1.getConversation().getSentAt()) && o2.getConversation() != null && Util.isUTCFormat(o2.getConversation().getSentAt()))
                    return format.parse(o1.getConversation().getSentAt()).compareTo(format.parse(o2.getConversation().getSentAt()));
                else
                    return -1;

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }              
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(channelsList, new Comparator<Channel>() {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN);

    @Override
    public int compare(Channel o1, Channel o2) {
        // If both are null, they are equal
        if (o1.getConversation() == null && o2.getConversation() == null)
            return 0;

        // If only first one is null, it is less than the other (null's come first)
        if (o1.getConversation() == null)
            return -1;

        // If only second one is null, it is greater than the other
        if (o2.getConversation() == null)
            return 1;

        Conversation c1 = o1.getConversation();
        Conversation c2 = o2.getConversation();

        // Same comparisons are done here again
        if (c1.getSentAt() == null && c2.getSentAt() == null)
            return 0;

        if (c1.getSentAt() == null)
            return -1;

        if (c2.getSentAt() == null)
            return 1;

        try {
            if (Util.isUTCFormat(o1.getConversation().getSentAt()) && Util.isUTCFormat(o2.getConversation().getSentAt()))
                return format.parse(o1.getConversation().getSentAt()).compareTo(format.parse(o2.getConversation().getSentAt()));
            else
                return -1;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }              
    }
});
```

Comment: @androidbash Then define how they should be sorted and implement it-if objects are equal their sort order is irrelevant. If you want to add structure beyond what you defined as your criteria then do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparator or comparable for sorting the array